# How to build a method to validate emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to create a method like so:

```
def email_is_junk(email_address)
end
```

Where it returns true if the email junk, false if the email is not junk... Tricky part is I want that logic to be based off conditions like the following:

user@domain.ext

- if the email has a + in the user,  email is junk
- if user contains the word do-not-reply or support, test, service, tips, twitter, alerts, survey, email is junk
- if the domain is craigslist.org, email is junk

Suggestions on how to write this method w/o requiring dozens of if blocks with regex?

Comment: No need to write dozens of blocks..only dozens of regex in an array that you can then loop over. Or for better(?) maintainability, write all the regex and possible strings to look for in a YAML/plaintext file and load that (ofcourse if you're going to be doing the checks *very* often then it's probably better to avoid the overhead of loading a file - but benchmark it and don't optimize unnecessarily).

Comment: Thanks, the checks will be very oftent. Can you show an example of how to loop over to do the check? Hopefully if a match is found it can break to be efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an illustration to Zabba's comment above:

```
USER_RULES = ['\+', 'do-not-reply', 'support', 'test', 'service', 'tips', 'twitter', 'alerts', 'survey']
DOMAIN_RULES = ['craigslist.org']

def email_is_junk(email)
  return true if !email.match('@') # return early if no @
  user, domain = email.split('@')
  USER_RULES.each   { |rule| return true if user.match(rule)   }
  DOMAIN_RULES.each { |rule| return true if domain.match(rule) }
  false # reached the end without matching anything
end
```

Comment: Maybe name the method "junk_email_address?" Also what is `email.split('0')` ?

Comment: Thanks but not sure I follow what's happening here. Doesn't the return need to be at the end?

Comment: Also, this errors with: dynamic constant assignment
    USER_RULES = ['+', 'do-not-reply', 'suppor...

Comment: moving USER_RULES and DOMAIN_RULES to lowercase seems to be required. Then it errors with: "RegexpError (invalid regular expression; there's no previous pattern, to which '+' would define cardinality at 1: /+/):"

Comment: Removing the '+' then yields the error "undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I lower cased USER_RULES & DOMAIN_RULES, removed the '+' item, and changed the 0 to an @, but the method still always returns true?

Comment: @zabba: Meant to split on the @, @ColdTree: yes needs to explicity return false at the end to signify it didn't match anything. Implicit return was DOMAIN_RULES before, which would be truish. Also, I started with the rules as methods and changed my mind to constants, and forgot to change the method, and failed to escape the +. In short I'm terribly sorry I posted without testing, especially while so tired. I updated my answer to address all these great comments.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Ruby's [`Regexp.union`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Regexp#union-class_method) and [`Regexp.escape`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Regexp#escape-class_method) methods. They make it easy to generate regex patterns based on text or regex strings.

This is from the `union` docs:

> Return a Regexp object that is the union of the given patterns, i.e., will match any of its parts. The patterns can be Regexp objects, in which case their options will be preserved, or Strings. If no patterns are given, returns /(?!)/. The behavior is unspecified if any given pattern contains capture.

```
Regexp.union                         #=> /(?!)/
Regexp.union("penzance")             #=> /penzance/
Regexp.union("a+b*c")                #=> /a\+b\*c/
Regexp.union("skiing", "sledding")   #=> /skiing|sledding/
Regexp.union(["skiing", "sledding"]) #=> /skiing|sledding/
Regexp.union(/dogs/, /cats/i)        #=> /(?-mix:dogs)|(?i-mx:cats)/
```

And from the `escape` docs:

> Escapes any characters that would have special meaning in a regular expression. Returns a new escaped string, or self if no characters are escaped. For any string, Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(str))=~str will be true.

```
Regexp.escape('\*?{}.')   #=> \\\*\?\{\}\.
```

This is a starting point:

```
patterns = [
  /.+?\+.+?@/
]  

strings = [
    'do-not-reply', 'support', 'test', 'service', 'tips', 'twitter', 'alerts', 'survey',
    'craigslist.org'
]

regex = Regexp.union(
  *patterns,
  *strings.map{ |s|
    Regexp.new( Regexp.escape("#{ s }@"), Regexp::IGNORECASE ) }
)
pp regex

>> /(?-mix:.+?\+.+?@)|(?i-mx:do\-not\-reply@)|(?i-mx:support@)|(?i-mx:test@)|(?i-mx:service@)|(?i-mx:tips@)|(?i-mx:twitter@)|(?i-mx:alerts@)|(?i-mx:survey@)|(?i-mx
```

Applying the above:

```
sample_email_addresses = %w[
    user
    user+foo
    do-not-reply
    support
    service
    tips
    twitter
    alerts
    survey
].map{ |e| e << '@host.com' }

pp sample_email_addresses.map{ |e| [e, !!e[regex]] }

>> [["user@host.com", false],
>> ["user+foo@host.com", true],
>> ["do-not-reply@host.com", true],
>> ["support@host.com", true],
>> ["service@host.com", true],
>> ["tips@host.com", true],
>> ["twitter@host.com", true],
>> ["alerts@host.com", true],
>> ["survey@host.com", true]]
```

The output shows a list containing each tested address. `true` means they triggered a hit in the regex, meaning there was something wrong, and `false` means they were clean and considered safe.

If you only want the ones that failed, i.e., matched the regex:

```
pp sample_email_addresses.select{ |e| e[regex] }

>> ["user+foo@host.com",
>>  "do-not-reply@host.com",
>>  "support@host.com",
>>  "service@host.com",
>>  "tips@host.com",
>>  "twitter@host.com",
>>  "alerts@host.com",
>>  "survey@host.com"]
```

If you only want the ones that passed, i.e., didn't trigger a hit in the regex:

```
pp sample_email_addresses.reject{ |e| e[regex] }

>> ["user@host.com"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative but how do you take this to make a method that returns true or false? Thanks Tin Man

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Javascript version. Not sure it can be much simpler than:

```
function isJunk(email) {
  return hasPlus(email) || supportLike(email) || craigsList(email);
}

function craigsList(email) {
  return email.match(/@craigslist\.org/);
}

function supportLike(email) {
  return email.match(/do-not-reply|support|test|service|tips|twitter|alerts|survey/);
}

function hasPlus(email) {
  return email.match(/\+.*@/);
}
```

This is only a heuristic, so it's not 100% accurate. If you still have problems, consider the verification by sending the user an email with a token in it.

Comment: "consider the verification by sending the user an email with a token in it." is the ONLY way to know for sure. Email addresses are too complex for even complex regexp.